# Installing db at AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm pretty newbie at aws. I've installed all I need at ec2 (free tier) and what left is db. I want to use Postgresql. I googled but I found so-called Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL (Beta). I'm not sure whether this was what I need. And what I need is just Postgresql. The question is, do I have to download and install Postgresql manually (via ssh) as if I did at my local computer or buy one somewhere at aws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use RDS. Everything is managed, and very easy to set up, but its not free.
2. Install PostgreSQL on your local instance. Will use more resources of your already very small instance. You should be able to install it using a package manager if you are on linux.

Comment: @Alex Yes, RDS is a separate service. Although they may have a free tier option.

Comment: one more thing, not related to this question: do I have to install web server in order to launch the website in Rails/Django/Scala/etc?

Comment: @Alex Generally yes. With most web application stacks its a good idea to set a web server in front of the application server.

Comment: at my local machine I can just do "rails s" or "rails thin" or "play". Can I do the same in ec2? Is this a good solution?

Comment: @Alex you will want to run rails as a daemon, independent of your terminal session. Look at something like phusion passenger.

Comment: Sure. But, suppose I ran 2 instances of Rails of the different port. Which one will be "visible" for the requests from the Internet, how do I specify it? I can create other question for this.

Comment: @Alex If both ports are open, then both would be visible. Without a web server to proxy the request, you would have to specify the port in the url. Using a web server, you can proxy requests to app1.yourdomain.com and app2.yourdomain.com via port 80.